# Add space to first 9th Sort ordinal numbers

Tags: bash, function

I have the following file and code

```
file.txt
field1      or      field1
field2              field2
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
field13             field8
field14             field9

awk '
function ordinal(i,   mod, str) {
   mod = i%10
   str = i
   if (i~/1[1-3]$/)  # for numbers ending in 11, 12, 13
      str = str "th"
   else if (mod==1)
      str = str "st"
   else if (mod==2)
      str = str "nd"
   else if (mod==3)
      str = str "rd"
   else
      str = str "th"
   return str
}
{ print ordinal(++i)")"" value : " $1}' file.txt
```

How can I add a space to ordinal numbers 1-9 when the fields is more than 10 and not when is less so that the columns are aligned

Τhe desired result is the following

```
 1st) value : field1    or      1st) value : field1
 2nd) value : field2            2nd) value : field2
.                               .
.                               .
.                               .
13th) value : field13           8th) value : field8
14th) value : field14           9th) value : field9
```

Comment: See: https://bl831.als.lbl.gov/~gmeigs/scripting_help/printf_awk_notes.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the first 9 records in an array. When you reach the tenth record then you pad the stored records:

```sh
awk '
    function header(i, s, m) {
        if ( i ~/1[1-3]$/) { s = "th" }
        else {
            m = i % 10
            if (m == 1) { s = "st" }
            else if (m == 2) { s = "nd" }
            else if (m == 3) { s = "rd" }
            else { s = "th" }
        }
        return i s ") value :" 
    }
    NR < 10 { prev[NR] = $0 }
    NR == 10 {
        for (i = 1; i < NR; i++) {
            print " " header(i), prev[i]
        }
    }
    NR >= 10 { print header(NR), $0 }
    END{
        if (NR-1 < 10) {
            for (i = 1; i < NR; i++) {
                print header(i), prev[i]
            }
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of awk to the `column` command

```
awk '
function ordinal(i,   mod, str) {
   mod = i%10
   str = i
   if (i~/1[1-3]$/)  # for numbers ending in 11, 12, 13
      str = str "th"
   else if (mod==1)
      str = str "st"
   else if (mod==2)
      str = str "nd"
   else if (mod==3)
      str = str "rd"
   else
      str = str "th"
   return str
}
{ print ordinal(++i)")"" value : " $1}' file.txt | column -t
```

Comment: Also good and simple solution but not excactly what I want. But thank you for your time to my problem.